# Extract face embedding - face recognition

Tags: machine-learning, face-recognition

I want to train a neural network to extract a number of (128) face features from an image.

The features are numbers that measure things like the distance between middles of the eyes, or the distance between middle of the left eyes and middle point of mouth.

I need this to find the dissimilarity between two faces: given a database with users, by analyzing a photo I'll be able to tell if it's a photo of Jhon.

I began my study using [this](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78http://) link, which states: *Researchers have discovered that the most accurate approach is to let the computer figure out the measurements to collect itself.*

Ok, so the output of the network is an array of 128 numbers, I'll use some formula to adjust the weights so the output numbers are as accurate as possible.

**What should I use as input?** Will my input nodes be three photos, like in [this](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78http://) article, and I'll extract the features based on the comparisons between the photos?

Comment: Your link is dead, it seems you are missing some basics and i would start learning from openface, a nice python + torch (lua) based implementation of the facenet paper, which learns this 2d-metric-embedding from data. It will also show you, that it's non-trivial (triplet-loss and co.).

Comment: I don't want to use a library. I want to do the training myself.

Comment: It's ready to be self-trained and i did not tell you to use it pretrained. Learn from it or don't, your decision. You can always start with the core-paper. Btw: ```i don't want to use it. I want to do the training myself``` might indicate one more misunderstanding, but maybe you got some reasons. The pretrained model is ready for usage on non-trained images, that's the whole point (of the metric-embedding approach).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought would be for you to use a library as [Openface](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/), which is already trained with lots of faces and has a great face representation (with the same 128 dimensions you need).

However, you mentioned that you want to train it yourself. I'd recommend you to start taking a look at Siamese Neural Networks. Siamese Neural Networks receive a pair of images (genuine pair - e.g. images from the same person; impostor pair - e.g. images from different persons) and try to learn a similarity/dissimilarity metric (also called Metric Learning). It is very useful for learning face embeddings since your goal seems to be related to that. They basically learn a way to map the input images to a representation that "benefits comparison". Other implementations (as OpenFace) are trained with Triplet Embeddings, where instead of a pair of images you receive a triple (two similar and one dissimilar).

Here are some references to start with Siamese Networks:

- Signature recognition (a little old but good to understand about them): https://papers.nips.cc/paper/769-signature-verification-using-a-siamese-time-delay-neural-network.pdf
- Siamese networks for face embeddings: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/chopra-05.pdf
- Triplet Embeddings paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03832.pdf

Just keep in mind that training these architectures is quite difficult, since selecting the best pairs is a very important and challenging part of the problem. One paper that mentions some of the challenges for creating image pairs  but is not related to faces is this [one](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~kb/publications/SIG15ProductNet.pdf).

Hope that helps!